# JQuery in Internet explorer not working at all but works perfectly in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, get

This code works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE8 ><

```
 <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

    $.get("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php", function(data){
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);

    });
 </script>
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php", function(data){
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);   
    });
})
```

Comment: external, but this works fine in chrome and firefox, is this not working because of cross scripting?

Comment: @AjayD3V Yes, I don't know how this works firefox, you should consider using jsonp.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's not working because of cross scripting, it's weird how it works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox though, but not in IE or Opera. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative way of doing it, and it actually gets the IP in IE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=DisplayIP";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
};

function DisplayIP(response) {
    document.getElementById("ipaddress").innerHTML = "Your IP Address is " 
                                                      + response.ip;
}
</script>

<span id="ipaddress"></span>
```